# How to lower an element at the same position as a button?

Tags: bootstrap-5

Do you know how I can lower the title to the same position as the button? I would like to do this with bootstrap without using css.

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML CSS JS</title>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
        <div class="breadcrumb d-flex justify-content-between border-bottom pt-5 ">
            <h3 class="text-center">Title </h3>
            <button type="button" (click)="goBack()" class="btn btn-primary m-1">Back</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try this @mercyto
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74844045/5235168

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add properties like
`text align-self-center m-1` to h3 tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML CSS JS</title>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
        <div class="breadcrumb d-flex justify-content-between border-bottom pt-5 ">
            <h3 class="text-center text align-self-center m-1">Title </h3>
            <button type="button" (click)="goBack()" class="btn btn-primary m-1">Back</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<h3 class="text-center">Title </h3>
```

Give this element position relative and give some top CSS as px as you need to position on there.